# How to calculate the tangent of x?

Tags: trigonometry

I've looked it up of course and got $\tan(x) = \cos(x)/\sin(x)$. For example $\tan(60) = \cos(60)/\sin(60)$ I get $0.32004$ but when I use a calculator I get $1.7320508075688772935274463415059$? Is this equation wrong? Please help.

Comment: that should be $\tan(x) = \sin(x)/\cos(x)$

Comment: $\tan { x } =\frac { \sin { x }  }{ \cos { x }  } $

Comment: Radians or degrees?

Comment: $\tan{60}=\frac{\sin{60}}{\cos{60}}$

Comment: This guy asked a valid question, and showed work hinting where he went wrong... doesn't deserve downvotes in my opinion

Comment: imo a question that can be answered simply opening the school mathbook or googoling "tangent" is not a valid question @jameselmore

Comment: I did look it up just got it mixed up a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that equation is completely wrong!  $\tan(x)= \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$.

It is $\cot(x)$ that is $\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there are multiple problems here. First of all: $\tan(x) = \sin(x)/\cos(x)$.
Then the other point is: There is a difference between calculating in degrees (cirlce has 360°) and calculating in radians (circle has $2\pi$). The 0.32004 result seems to suggest radians, but 1.7320 suggests degree.

Answer (score 0):

The result shown by calculator is right.
Because tan(x)=sin(x)/cos(x)
is tan(60)=sin(60)/cos(60)
   tan(60)=(√3/2)/(1/2)
   tan(60)= √3= 1.73(approx)

- tan(x)!=cos(x)/sin(x)
- cot(x)= cos(x)/sin(x)

Answer (score 0):

You got 0.32004 by dividing sin 60 radians with cos 60radians ! Now you should choose angle input as radians or degrees before using calculator.Check known angles like $ \sin 30 {^0} = \frac12$ before using it to make sure.